# Why did BA 199 fly a missed approach followed by circles?

Tags: flight-path, missed-approach

I just saw G-YMML (operating as BA 199) execute a missed approach and make weird circles. What is happening here? ([FlightAware permalink](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/BAW199/history/20190704/2035Z/EGLL/VOHS))

[image: in]

Comment: https://thebasource.com/british-airways-b777-200er-g-ymml-ba199-hyderabad-diversion/ says it eventually diverted to Hyderabad, then flew to Mumbai later. But it does not state the reason. Trawling the site of DCGA or AIB might return something more, but it's harder to search.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the aircraft went missed approach because of an unsafe gear indication or flight control issue and the crew wanted to try and rectify or troubleshoot the issue and was given that general area east of the airport and away from the normal traffic flow to work the problem (doing 360 turns in process).

Difficult to say for certain.

Comment: I have the same comment as for the deleted answers—those 360s look a little too perfect compared to their movement across the ground, *if* wind was the only reason they didn't stay over the same spot. So why would they move across the ground, if not wind?

Comment: The map clearly shows they did not just depart, so it's down to the second option. It's obviously hard to tell what exactly they were troubleshooting.

Comment: @randomhead -- re the issue of the shape of the circles, and the comment under the deleted question that they "all look pretty circle-y" -- I guess I don't agree-- the mere fact that they are not completely staying in the same place on the trace, is proof that they are not round, but rather have a longer downwind leg and a shorter upwind leg.  Of course, the wind is clearly only a small fraction of the aircraft flight speed, otherwise the "circles" would be much more stretched out into a series of non-round "curlicues".

Comment: Anyway, to me they seem consistent w/ an aircraft maintaining a constant bank angle (likely by autopilot) and aspd, in a steady (light) wind.  Just had another thought-- would be interesting to go back and check the reported wind conditions, though surface winds might have been too light to give much insight--

Comment: @quietflyer Agreed; this is exactly what you’d get flying constant-bank circles without correcting for wind. I’m curious why ATC didn’t give them holding instructions, though.

Comment: @StephenS: if the crew was doing circles while troubleshooting ATC could have just told them to remain east of a specific point (dme or rnav fix, etc.). The distraction for the crew to remain in a specific holding pattern while focusing on troubleshooting likely unnecessary. As a controller, I would give them a general location to remain (outside of the normal traffic flow) and then keep an eye on the aircraft's position.  But we are still just guessing what the circumstances actually were.

Comment: @757toga It only takes a few button pushes to set up a hold at a GPS fix. I’m not even sure how to get my autopilot to make a constant-bank turn indefinitely.

Comment: @StephenS: I am aware of that. But we're still unaware of what the circumstances were and obviously they were not in a typical holding pattern so the issue must have been something where that wasn't the best course of action.